# Scrapy - how to manage pagination without 'Next' button?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping the content of articles from a site like [this](https://www.gosc.pl/doc/791526.Zaloz-zbroje/) where there is no 'Next' button to follow. `ItemLoader` is passed from `parse_issue` in the `response.meta` object as well as some additional data like `section_name`. Here is the function:

```
     def parse_article(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Parse function called parse_article on {}'.format(response.url))
        acrobat = response.xpath('//div[@class="txt__lead"]/p[contains(text(), "Plik do pobrania w wersji (pdf) - wymagany Acrobat Reader")]')
        limiter = response.xpath('//p[@class="limiter"]')
        if not acrobat and not limiter:
            loader = ItemLoader(item=response.meta['periodical_item'].copy(), response=response)
            loader.add_value('section_name', response.meta['section_name'])
            loader.add_value('article_url', response.url)
            loader.add_xpath('article_authors', './/p[@class="l doc-author"]/b')
            loader.add_xpath('article_title', '//div[@class="cf txt "]//h1')
            loader.add_xpath('article_intro', '//div[@class="txt__lead"]//p')
            article_content = response.xpath('.//div[@class=" txt__rich-area"]//p').getall()
            # # check for pagiantion
            next_page_url = response.xpath('//span[@class="pgr_nrs"]/span[contains(text(), 1)]/following-sibling::a[1]/@href').get()
            if next_page_url:
                # I'm not sure what should be here... Something like this: (???)
                yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse_article, meta={
                'periodical_item' : loader.load_item(),
                'article_content' : article_content
                })
            else:
                loader.add_xpath('article_content', article_content)
                yield loader.load_item()
```

The problem is in `parse_article` function: I don't know how to combine the content of paragraphs from all pages into the one item. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: You're currently crawling a single news article. Why would you be checking for pagination? Does a single news article have pagination? Isn't this url `https://www.gosc.pl/Tygodnik/Temat_numeru` the list of news articles that has pagination?

Comment: Hi, thanks for response!Yes, a single news article has pagination. Like here: `https://www.gosc.pl/doc/791526.Zaloz-zbroje/` and I don't know how to connect content from all four pages.

Comment: Add content of page to `article_content` as list the join if you want to have single string or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `parse_article` looks good. If the issue is just adding the `article_content` to the loader, you just needed to fetch it from the `response.meta`:

I would update this line:

```
article_content = response.meta.get('article_content', '') + response.xpath('.//div[@class=" txt__rich-area"]//p').getall()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the next page URL to iterate over X amount.

I noticed that article had 4 pages but some could be more

They are simply distinguished by adding /2 or /3 to the end of the URL e.g

```
https://www.gosc.pl/doc/791526.Zaloz-zbroje/
https://www.gosc.pl/doc/791526.Zaloz-zbroje/2
https://www.gosc.pl/doc/791526.Zaloz-zbroje/3
```

I don't use scrapy. But when I need multiple pages I would normally just iterate.

When you first scrape the page. Find the max amount of pages for that article first . On that site for example it says 1/4 so you know you will need 4 pages in total.

```
url = "https://www.gosc.pl/doc/791526.Zaloz-zbroje/"
data_store = ""
for i in range(1, 5):
    actual_url = "{}{}".format(url, I)
    scrape_stuff = content_you_want
    data_store += scrape_stuff

# format the collected data
```

Comment: Yeah, but iterating through pages are not the real issue here... the problem I encountered is that I don't know how to pass in Scrapy `article_content` from all 4 pages to one `loader`...

Comment: So what information are you sending to the function??

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this as I could help with this more now :)